# Rotation on iOS device stops working when modal presented

Tags: ios, autolayout, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have an iOS app for iPhone and iPad with supported interface orientations as Portrait (both) and Landscape (both). I have rotation code in `viewWillTransitionToSize` in all view controllers in the app. I present a modal from my ViewController in storyboard. When the modal is presented, the rotation code and auto layout constraints stop getting called in all view controllers - the one pushed and the topmost modal VC as well.

Here is the code that presents, for example, a view controller. The segue is of kind "Present Modally".

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PreviewModal"]) {

        PreviewViewController *previewViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        [self.stillCamera capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:self.exposureFilter withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *processedImage, NSError *error) {
            UIImage *rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:processedImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
            previewViewController.previewImage.image = rotatedImage;
            previewViewController.presetType = self.presetString;
        }];
    }
}
```

I also go back with an unwind segue but there is no code in that unwind, it's just an empty unwind back to ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I've had quite similar problem, but managed to solve it just a few minutes ago. In my case issue were in private variable declaration code (which isn't mine). Method `supportedInterfaceOrientations:` logic is related to private variable `allowRotation`, which was defined this way:

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController
int allowRotateVal = NO;
...
-(void)allowRotate:(BOOL)val
{
  allowRotateVal = val;
}
@end
```

And somehow (don't yet understand how) it were overwritten by other instance of same navigation controller which is used for presenting modal view controller. I've even tried putting breakpoint to setter method, but it I didn't see anything special. By simply rewriting private variable declaration this way:

```
@interface CustomNavigationController () {
  int allowRotateVal;
}
@end

@implementation CustomNavigationController
...
@end
```

Everything started to work like expected. A miracle? :)